# How to make sure the letters 'pez' do not convert to a fish symbol?

Tags: encoding, characters

I have one field in a profile that converts the letters 'pez' into a fish symbol. It doesn't happen anywhere else throughout the site. Any suggestions on why this is happening and how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you please edit your question and add the code that does the character conversion?

Comment: I think the font you are using for the orange text portion has a glyph for that.

Comment: This is a bug in the version of Andada that is served by google fonts—it has a ligature for the letters 'pez' that is a fish for some reason. It has nothing to do with WordPress or your WordPress Plugins. If you can serve your own font, download Andada from www.huertatipografica.com and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

This does not happen out of the box in WordPress.  I would recommend going through your plugins one by one and deactivate them to see which plugin is causing this.

After that if it still persists, try switching to one of the themes that comes with stock WordPress.  If the issue goes away there then there is something in your theme causing this conversion.

Comment: Thank you Stephanie. It most likely is a plugin because I don't believe we have had this issue before. Then again, I don't think we've had another 'Lopez' before.